# Наследование класса с абстрактным методом, принимающим в качестве аргумента список наследников этого класса

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, generics

Есть такой код:

```
public abstract class MyObject  {
    private volatile int id;

    public synchronized int getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }

    public abstract <T extends MyObject> int compareTo(T object);

    public boolean inList(List<? extends MyObject> list)
    {
        for (MyObject myobject : list)
            if (this.compareTo(myobject) == 0)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Как мне унаследовать класс, чтобы метод `inList()` принимал объект `List<ChildClass> list`, а не `List<? extends MyObject> list`? То же касается и аргумента метода `compareTo()`

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class MyObject<T extends MyObject>
```

а в методах использовать T

```
public abstract <T> int compareTo(T object);

public boolean inList(List<T> list)
{
    for (MyObject myobject : list)
        if (this.compareTo(myobject) == 0)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Создавая наследника можно указать на себя же

```
public abstract class ChildClass extends MyObject<ChildClass>
```

соответственно при переопределении T заменится на ChildClass

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод со следующей сигнатурой

```
public <T extends MyObject> boolean inList(List<T> list);
```